# What is a latent bug?

Tags: manual-testing, terminology

I came to know a new bug type named latent bug. Kindly help me understand what kind of bug is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [dictionary](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/latent+defect):

> **latent defect** n. a hidden flaw, weakness or imperfection in an article
>   which a seller knows about, but the buyer cannot discover by
>   reasonable inspection.

Think this term is more used for selling physical items (like houses and cars) and not in software.

From [some random site](http://careerride.com/Testing-latent-bugs-and-golden-bug.aspx):

> **latent bug**: The bug that is not identified in the past versions of the software application

In software it might also be a defect the developers know about, but do not tell the testers or the end-client.

Answer (score 1):

Latent bugs are bugs which exist, but have not yet been discovered.

They are bugs waiting to be found.

also see: http://www.allthingsquality.com/p/testing-terms-glossary.html

Answer (score 1):

In Software Quality Assurance:

Latent defects are the those which arises in the field, and unknown until they reported by the field staff.

More bugs during development phase, chances are more latent defects will be.

Comment: Interesting that more latent bugs might be in the final product. Are the any rules maybe a ratio compared to the found issues during development? Do you have proof that this is actually true? Although it sounds logical :)

Comment: I would recommend you to go through the book, "Software Quality Metrics Overview" by Pearson: 
Link to the book: http://www.pearsonhighered.com/samplechapter/0201729156.pdf
In this book you will find many product reliability growth models with different metrics that will help in understanding what rules applied when chances of more latent defects occurrence are there. It will also explain the context through which we can understand easily what is a latent defect or bug in a software product.