# What is the difference between Gold bug and Latent bug?

Tags: manual-testing, agile-testing, terminology

There are two different bugs, Gold and Latent. Both exists in application from (lets say) Sprint 1. I would be thankful if you could tell me the difference between Gold bug and Latent bug?

Answer (score 8):

**Latent Bug** : A latent bug is a bug which is present in the system from previous iterations or release (in your scenario Sprint 1). They are either low priority bugs, which either went undetected or were not reported.

Here is a good description : [What is a latent bug?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9170/what-is-a-latent-bug)

**Golden Bug** : If a bug happens to appear, in every iteration or release, affecting the major module, with high priority and high severity, then it would be classified as a golden bug.

Comment: Whosoever downvoted this can you please explain the reason for same :(

Answer (score 3):

**Latent Bug:** The bug that's not known within the past versions of the software application

**Golden Bug:** The bug that's occurred in each instances of the application with severity level high and with high priority.

- Bugs that stay dormant or hidden are latent bugs. These bugs aren't found till one or a lot of releases of the product.
- Golden bugs are bugs which will have an effect on the essential functionality of the system.

Answer (score 2):

**What is Latent Bug?**

•   The latent bug is not identified in the older versions of the software app

•   Bugs that remain unhidden or dormant are called as the latent bugs

•   These bugs are not found until 1 or more releases of the product

•   Illustration of latent bugs can be the date issues such as the y2k

[image]

**What is Golden Bug?**

•   The Golden bug that is occurred in each instance of the app with severity level high and with high priority.

•   These bugs are can affect the critical functionality of the software app or system.

•   The illustration can be behavior related to the prime functionality

Answer (score 0):

- **Latent Bug:** The bug that is not identified in the past versions of the software application. which is not fetch or display in past versions of the system.

  Also refer this Link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_defect
- **Golden Bug:** The bug that is occurred in every instances of the application with severity level high and with high priority.

  Also refer this Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gold-Bug

Comment: I followed your Gold Bug link.  Had no idea Edgar Allen Poe's stories were allegories for software testing.  Was it a coincidence that I found this around Halloween?

Answer (score 0):

**Both the bugs are related to manual testing:**

**Latent Bug:**
Bugs that remail dormant unhidden are latent bugs. These bugs are not found until one or more releases of the product.

Example: These can be related to date issues like the y2k.

**Golden Bug:**
Golden Bugs are the bugs that affect the critical/major functionalities in our application build

Example: Mainly behavior related to your premium functionality and some times savior or show-stopper

Answer (score -1):

- Latent Bug - A bug that has been unobserved on two or more release
- Golden Bug - The bug that is occurred in every instances of the
  application with severity level high and with high priority.

Comment: You paraphrased half of an answer from four months ago.